# Input parameter validation for "optional" parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing a SQL query and I'm stuck on the WHERE clause. What I'm trying to do with the last line is say, if no value has been input for the parameter, use the * argument (all values).

```
WHERE
(REGEXP_INSTR('%params', '///') > 0 AND REGEXP_LIKE(column1,'%params'))
OR (REGEXP_INSTR('%params', '///') = 0 AND REGEXP_LIKE('%params'))
OR (REGEXP_INSTR('%params', '') = 1
```

It's the last line I'm having an issue with:

```
OR (REGEXP_INSTR('%params', '') = 1
```

All runtime parameters must have a value, so this can't be NULL value.

I'm not sure if ' ' will work, or might exibit some unwanted behaviour.

Comment: What is `REGEXP_LIKE('%params')` supposed to be doing, other than generating  a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle treats `''` as `NULL`, so you cannot do what you want.  You need a direct comparison to `NULL`:

```
WHERE (REGEXP_INSTR('%params', '///') > 0 AND REGEXP_LIKE(column1,'%params')) OR
      (REGEXP_INSTR('%params', '///') = 0 AND REGEXP_LIKE('%params')) OR
      ('%params' IS NULL)
```

Even if `''` where not `NULL`, looking for an empty string in another string doesn't really make sense.

You could also use `LENGTH()`, but you have to be careful because it actually returns `NULL` rather than `0`.

Comment: I thought runtime parameters must all have a value, otherwise we'll get a parameter validation?